How to retrieve transaction quantity and remark information for any transaction using solana api
I am receiving arrays labeled preBalances and postBalances, but I am unable to locate the specific information I need.
I attempted to use the getTransaction function, but I couldn't find the transaction quantity and remark information. Could you please assist me?
